# Как проверить массив строк на определенный символ

Tags: javascript

Необходимо преобразовать массив строк(преобразовывается он правильно). Но нужно чтобы преобразования были только со словами("!", "?" и т п не нужно). Как это можно сделать с помощью регулярок?

```
function pigIt(str){
    let buffer = str.split(' ');

    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        if(buffer[i] === /[a-zA-Z]/) {
            buffer[i] = buffer[i] + buffer[i][0];
            buffer[i] = buffer[i].slice(1) + 'ay';
        }
    }

    return buffer.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ');
}
```

Пример строки (pigIt('Pig latin is cool !'),'igPay atinlay siay oolcay !')

Comment: добавьте пример строки

Comment: добавил пример строки

Comment: а регуляркой нельзя сперва вырезать все символы а потом делать `split('')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "(pigIt('Pig latin is cool !'),'igPay atinlay siay oolcay !')"
let res = str.match(/\w+/g)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вы выводите вообще не то что нужно автору. Нужно было из строки: "Pig latin is cool !" получить "igPay atinlay siay oolcay !"

Answer (score 0):

`buffer[i] === /[a-zA-Z]/` — проверка на совпадение так не делается, такое сравнение даст true, только если в `buffer[i]` такая же регулярка (а там строка).

Регулярка тоже неправильная, она при проверке даст true, если во всей строке есть хотя бы одна буква. Нужно проверить, что от начала строки `^` до конца строки `$` есть только последовательность букв `+` (одна или много).

```js
function pigIt(str){
    let buffer = str.split(' ');

    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        if(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(buffer[i])) {
            buffer[i] = buffer[i] + buffer[i][0];
            buffer[i] = buffer[i].slice(1) + 'ay';
        }
    }

    return buffer.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ');
}

console.log(
    pigIt('Pig latin moo? is cool !')
);
```

Можно сократить до `/^[a-z]+$/i` (i - insensitive);

Answer (score 0):

- Регулярку изменил на `/^[a-z]+$/i` - позволяет определять строки, которые состоят только из английских букв без учёта регистра
- Применять к массиву `toString`, а потом `replace` - в вашем случае абсолютно бессмысленно. Вместо этого можно воспользоваться методом `join`
- Уместил всё в "одну строку" :)

```js
const pigIt = (str) => str
  .split(' ')
  .map(word => /^[a-z]+$/i.test(word) ? (word.slice(1) + word[0] + 'ay') : word)
  .join(' ');

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool!'));
```